# How do I use filter inside a controller (JS)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, controller

this is my first post here so I also appreciate advice on how to post better. I'm wondering how do I use filters inside a controller?

I have this class/controller to add products:

```
class ProductController {
constructor() {
    this.allProductItems = [];
}// end of constructor

//methods
addProduct(product, productName, productID, productPrice, productDescription, productTrivia, productImg, recoDelivery, productRemarks, productCategory){

    const productItem = {
        Product: product,
        name: productName,
        id: productID,
        price: productPrice,
        desc: productDescription,
        trivia: productTrivia,
        img: productImg,
        recoDelivery: recoDelivery,
        remarks: productRemarks,
        category: productCategory,

    } //end of productitem

    this.allProductItems.push(productItem);
    console.log(this.allProductItems)

} // end of addproduct
```

Then I have an instance of the class which is:

```
const products = new ProductController();

products.addProduct("Lemongrass Bodywash", "Bodywash, Lemongrass, 500ml", "04", 25, "Treat your skin and let it heal after a long day. Rinse away the dirt and grime of life with the scent of lemongrass and natural oils.", "From 1936 to 1950, a cartel of motor and oil companies successfully conspired to replace rail transport in Los Angeles with buses.", "images/menbodywash.jpg", 2, "E", "F");
```

I want to filter according to say, price > 25.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
const filterProductItems = this.allProductItems.filter(productEx => productEx.productPrice > 50);
console.log(filterProductItems);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code.

```js
const filterProductItems = this.allProductItems.filter(productEx => productEx.price > 25);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are checking for the wrong key

`productPrice` instead of `price`

your code seems to work fine

```js
class ProductController {
  constructor() {
    this.allProductItems = [];
  } // end of constructor

  //methods
  addProduct(product, productName, productID, productPrice, productDescription, productTrivia, productImg, recoDelivery, productRemarks, productCategory) {

    const productItem = {
      Product: product,
      name: productName,
      id: productID,
      price: productPrice,
      desc: productDescription,
      trivia: productTrivia,
      img: productImg,
      recoDelivery: recoDelivery,
      remarks: productRemarks,
      category: productCategory,

    } //end of productitem

    this.allProductItems.push(productItem);
    console.log(this.allProductItems)

  } // end of addproduct
}

const products = new ProductController();

products.addProduct("Lemongrass Bodywash", "Bodywash, Lemongrass, 500ml", "04", 25, "Treat your skin and let it heal after a long day. Rinse away the dirt and grime of life with the scent of lemongrass and natural oils.", "From 1936 to 1950, a cartel of motor and oil companies successfully conspired to replace rail transport in Los Angeles with buses.", "images/menbodywash.jpg", 2, "E", "F");

console.log(products.allProductItems.filter(p => p.price > 25))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this will work for you.

```js
class ProductController {
    constructor() {
      this.allProductItems = [];
    }// end of constructor

    //methods
    addProduct(product, productName, productID, productPrice, productDescription, productTrivia, productImg, recoDelivery, productRemarks, productCategory){

        const productItem = {
            Product: product,
            name: productName,
            id: productID,
            price: productPrice,
            desc: productDescription,
            trivia: productTrivia,
            img: productImg,
            recoDelivery: recoDelivery,
            remarks: productRemarks,
            category: productCategory,
        } //end of productitem

        this.allProductItems.push(productItem);
        // console.log(this.allProductItems)''

    } // end of addproduct
}

const products = new ProductController();
products.addProduct("Lemongrass Bodywash", "Bodywash, Lemongrass, 500ml", "04", 25, "Treat your skin and let it heal after a long day. Rinse away the dirt and grime of life with the scent of lemongrass and natural oils.", "From 1936 to 1950, a cartel of motor and oil companies successfully conspired to replace rail transport in Los Angeles with buses.", "images/menbodywash.jpg", 2, "E", "F");
products.addProduct("Coke", "Bodywash, Lemongrass, 500ml", "04", 100, "Treat your skin and let it heal after a long day. Rinse away the dirt and grime of life with the scent of lemongrass and natural oils.", "From 1936 to 1950, a cartel of motor and oil companies successfully conspired to replace rail transport in Los Angeles with buses.", "images/menbodywash.jpg", 2, "E", "F");

console.log(products.allProductItems.filter(product => product.price > 25));
```